# How to configure NGINX to serve files with custom extension with gzip compression?

Tags: nginx

I can enable nginx gzip compression for MIME types. I however need to serve large files which have a different extension (.roadData). A .roadData is essentially json.

How can I ask nginx to serve .roadData files with compression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the MIME type for your custom extensions, like the following:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    types {
        application/json roadData;
    }
}
```

Then all the `.roadData` files will be served with the appropriate MIME type, and NGINX will compress them if you have specified that type for compression.

In this way, you extend the server-wide MIME-types with your own, for another extension.

Alternatively, you can specify it as default for location, provided that `roadData` are stored in a single directory withou other files:

```
location /download/ {
    types        { }
    default_type application/json;
}
```

Like the other answer mentions, pre-compressed gzip files make sense there, because you don't want NGINX to recompress those large files on every request.

Use `gzip_static on;` and create a compressed version of the files.

One of the most efficient tools there would be [`zopfli`](https://github.com/google/zopfli).

Answer (score 0):

add mime type for your extension

```
types {
 application/json roadData;
}
```

enable compression for your mime type

```
gzip_static  on;
gzip  on;
gzip_types  application/json;
```

to offload nginx from dynamic compression create .gz (filename.roadData.gz) files next to original files so nginx will response with pre-compressed files.